# How to Handle Hash Table with Some Dual Values? Working with Strings

Tags: powershell, active-directory, hashtable

I'm given the task to lookup user departments in AD, then match those to a department manual that is in a lookup CSV cross reference file. They have 1 code for each department which maps to 1 manual, except for some cases where a department may get 2 different manuals.

File 1:

```
Code    Manual
A   Administrative
B   Ambulatory Care
C   Anatomic Pathology & Clinical Laboraties
```

File 2:

```
AD Departments  Code
300P RENEWAL    A3
ACCOUNTING OPERATIONS   A11
ACCOUNTS PAYABLE    A11
ACCREDITATION   A
ADVANCED LUNG DISEASE   B
AGING ADULT SERVICES    A3
ANESTHESIA  A6
APP - INPATIENT A3
B2  A3
BENEFITS MANAGEMENT A11
BLOOD TRANSFUSION SERVICES  A3
BMT SERVICE LINES   B
Business Development    V
BUSINESS OPS&STRATEGIC INIT V
BW DIGESTIVE HEALTH CENTER  B, V
```

This code works fine if a department maps one to one with the file, but in the case where an AD department has 2 codes (for 2 different manuals), it seems to only grab the first one. Is there an easy way to list both like in the last BW DIGESTIVE HEALTH CENTER where they need manuals B and V? Ideally, `$DeptMan` would be able to list 2 values where needed.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$Depts | ForEach-Object {
    $Table1[$_.'AD Departments'] = $_
}

$Manuals | ForEach-Object {
    $Table2[$_.Code] = $_
}

$Managers = Get-ADUser -Filter {some filter} -pr SamaccountName,GivenName,Initials, SN,Company,Title,Department

foreach ($Man in $Managers) {
    $Dept    = $Man.Department 
    $Code    = $Table1.Item("$Dept")
    $CodeMap = $Code.code
    $Manual  = $Table2.Item("$CodeMap")
    $DeptMan = $Manual.Manual

    $Man |
        select @{Name="SID";Expression={$Man.SamAccountName}},
            @{Name="FirstName";Expression={$Man.givenName}},
            @{Name="Initials";Expression={$Man.Initials}},
            @{Name="LastName";Expression={$Man.sn}},
            @{Name="Department";Expression={$Man.Department}},
            @{Name="Email";Expression={$Man.Mail}},
            @{Name="Manual";Expression={$DeptMan}} |
        Export-Csv C:\output.csv -NoType -Append
}
```

Comment: Split the codes at `, ` and run the body of your loop for each code (`$Table1[$Dept] | ForEach-Object { ... }`).

Comment: How exactly are you expecting to export nested arrays to a CSV? What is your desired output for the last item's "Manual" column?

Comment: I'm assuming the requestor wants output similar to manual1, manual2. Let me try Ansgar's idea.

Comment: Hi Ansgar, tried splitting at the comma but it's still not working. I thought of adding a $CodeMap2 that takes the value after the comma, but then when I try another lookup and then Name/Expression like @{Name="Manua2l";Expression={$DeptMan2}} for instance, it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally figured it out. You have to reset the variables in the foreach loop and also change the $codes to strings or they don't evaluate to True or False. Once I got into the If block, I just recreated new manual variables and it seems to work. Everything else I posted at the beginning of my initial script has not changed. Hope this helps someone out.

```
foreach ($Man in $Managers) {

    $DeptMan = $Null
    $DeptMan1 = $Null

    $Dept = $Man.Department 

    $Code = $Table1.item("$Dept")

    [string]$CodeMap = $code.code

    $Manual = $Table2.item("$CodeMap")

    $DeptMan = $Manual.Manual

    if ($CodeMap -like "*,*") {$CodeMap1 = $code.code.Split(", ",[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries) 

                                [string]$CodeMap2 = $CodeMap1[0] 

                                [string]$CodeMap3 = $CodeMap1[1]

                                $Manual1 = $Table2.item("$CodeMap2")

                                $Manual2 = $Table2.item("$CodeMap3")

                                $DeptMan = $Manual1.Manual

                                $DeptMan1 = $Manual2.Manual

                                }

   $Man | select @{Name="SID";Expression={$Man.SamAccountName}},
                 @{Name="FirstName";Expression={$Man.givenName}},
                 @{Name="Initials";Expression={$Man.Initials}},
                 @{Name="LastName";Expression={$Man.sn}},
                 @{Name="Department";Expression={$Man.Department}},
                 @{Name="Email";Expression={$Man.Mail}},
                 @{Name="Manual1";Expression={$DeptMan}},
                 @{Name="Manual2";Expression={$DeptMan1}}| export-csv C:\Scripts\1-Manuals_$((Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy')).csv -NoTypeInformation -append 


    }
```